# Select row on click react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am trying to find the best table to use with my react apps, and for now, the [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) offers everything I need (pagination, server-side control, filtering, sorting, footer row).

This being said, I can't seem to be able to select a row. There are no [examples](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/simple-table) that show this.

Some things, that I have tried include trying to set a className on click of the row. But I can't seem to find the calling element in `e` nor `t`. Also, I don't like this approach, because it is not how a react app should do things.

```
<ReactTable
            ...
            getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
                return {
                    onClick: (e, t) => {
                        t.srcElement.classList.add('active')
                    },
                    style: {
                    }
                }
            }}
        />
```

Some possible workaround would be to render checkboxes as a first column, but this is not optimal as it limits the area to click to 'activate' the row. Also, the visual feedback will be less expressive.

Am I missing the elephant in the room? And if not, do you know another library that supports the things that I've described earlier?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
Another option, this being open source, is to suggest an edit. And maybe this is the proper thing to do.

**EDIT 2**

Another thing, suggested by Davorin Ruševljan in the comments, but I couldn't make it work was:

```
onRowClick(e, t, rowInfo) {
    this.setState((oldState) => {
        let data = oldState.data.slice();
        let copy = Object.assign({},  data[rowInfo.index]);

        copy.selected = true;
        copy.FirstName = "selected";
        data[rowInfo.index] = copy;

        return {
            data: data,
        }
    })
}

....

            getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column) => {
                return {
                    onClick: (e, t) => { this.onRowClick(e, t, rowInfo) },
                    style: {
                        background: rowInfo && rowInfo.row.selected ? 'green' : 'red'
                    }
                }
            }}
```

This sets the 'FirstName' column to 'selected', but does not set the class to 'green'

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I found the solution after a few tries, I hope this can help you. Add the following to your `<ReactTable>` component:

```
getTrProps={(state, rowInfo) => {
  if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
    return {
      onClick: (e) => {
        this.setState({
          selected: rowInfo.index
        })
      },
      style: {
        background: rowInfo.index === this.state.selected ? '#00afec' : 'white',
        color: rowInfo.index === this.state.selected ? 'white' : 'black'
      }
    }
  }else{
    return {}
  }
}
```

In your `state` don't forget to add a null `selected` value, like:

```
state = { selected: null }
```

Comment: Can this do multiple selection?

Comment: i guess you can but you have to implement a custom logic to store the selected indexes

Comment: worked for me too, but I also had to check that  `rowinfo !== undefined` to avoid runtime errors

Comment: Doesn't it only work when you click on the checkbox? How can we make it work when clicking anywhere within a row?

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon I know this is long closed, but I was wondering what value I pass in for rowInfo?

Comment: @junBin @duncanrager @ErlendV Hey all, I added the `rowinfo !== undefined` but am unable to get rid of a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined" Any thoughts? I am thinking rowInfo should probably be set somewhere outside the props

Comment: @ErlendV where did you add the undefined check? Could you assist?

Comment: @YoungScooter did you affect `that` with `this` ? did you update the state on click ?

Comment: Yea I did all of that. Found the solution in another thread. I had to add an else { return {}} after the if (!undefined). Pretty random. I appreciate the response though.

Comment: i glad you found it @YoungScooter , can you link me the thread in order to edit my anwser ? thank by advance !

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon Sorry for the late response. Found the link, here it is! https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/issues/233

Comment: HI, can someone kindly explain how come my rowInfo is compaining as undefined? I am not sure how to use the `getTrProps` method properly

Comment: @AKJ i believe this only works with react-table v6. v7 doesn't have `getTrProps`, so this answer won't work.

Answer (score 23):

There is a HOC included for React-Table that allows for selection, even when filtering and paginating the table, the setup is slightly more advanced than the basic table so read through the info in the link below first. 

[image]

After importing the HOC you can then use it like this with the necessary methods:

```
/**
* Toggle a single checkbox for select table
*/
toggleSelection(key: number, shift: string, row: string) {
    // start off with the existing state
    let selection = [...this.state.selection];
    const keyIndex = selection.indexOf(key);

    // check to see if the key exists
    if (keyIndex >= 0) {
        // it does exist so we will remove it using destructing
        selection = [
            ...selection.slice(0, keyIndex),
            ...selection.slice(keyIndex + 1)
        ];
    } else {
        // it does not exist so add it
        selection.push(key);
    }
    // update the state
    this.setState({ selection });
}

/**
* Toggle all checkboxes for select table
*/
toggleAll() {
    const selectAll = !this.state.selectAll;
    const selection = [];

    if (selectAll) {
        // we need to get at the internals of ReactTable
        const wrappedInstance = this.checkboxTable.getWrappedInstance();
        // the 'sortedData' property contains the currently accessible records based on the filter and sort
        const currentRecords = wrappedInstance.getResolvedState().sortedData;
        // we just push all the IDs onto the selection array
        currentRecords.forEach(item => {
            selection.push(item._original._id);
        });
    }
    this.setState({ selectAll, selection });
}

/**
* Whether or not a row is selected for select table
*/
isSelected(key: number) {
    return this.state.selection.includes(key);
}

<CheckboxTable
    ref={r => (this.checkboxTable = r)}
    toggleSelection={this.toggleSelection}
    selectAll={this.state.selectAll}
    toggleAll={this.toggleAll}
    selectType="checkbox"
    isSelected={this.isSelected}
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
/>
```

**See here for more information:**
https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6#selecttable

**Here is a working example:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-select-j9jvw

Comment: This seems like the best approach. Selection is supported by react-table through this higher order component.

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with, react-table, so I do not know it has direct support for selecting and deselecting (it would be nice if it had).

If it does not, with the piece of code you already have you can install the onCLick handler. Now instead of trying to attach style directly to row, you can modify state, by for instance adding selected: true to row data. That would trigger rerender. Now you only have to override how are rows with selected === true rendered. Something along lines of:

```
// Any Tr element will be green if its (row.age > 20) 
<ReactTable
  getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column) => {
    return {
      style: {
        background: rowInfo.row.selected ? 'green' : 'red'
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the replay, @Davorin! I don't think that this will be of any use, because I don't have any control over the state of the table and therefore I cannot set rowInfo.row.selected.. without calling this.setState, the table will not rerender

Comment: How do you mean you do not have control, you are supplying table  with data property, change it in data

Comment: What I meant was that getTrProps is not part of the rerendering of the page, when the data is changed. And setting new data to the table does not invoke it, unfortunately. I am going to edit my question with the way that I am trying to do it.

Answer (score 3):

if u want to have multiple selection on select row..

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import 'react-table/react-table.css';
import { ReactTableDefaults } from 'react-table';
import matchSorter from 'match-sorter';


class ThreatReportTable extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    selected: [],
    row: []
  }
}
render(){

  const columns = this.props.label;

  const data = this.props.data;

  Object.assign(ReactTableDefaults, {
    defaultPageSize: 10,
    pageText: false,
    previousText: '<',
    nextText: '>',
    showPageJump: false,
    showPagination: true,
    defaultSortMethod: (a, b, desc) => {
    return b - a;
  },


  })

    return(
    <ReactTable className='threatReportTable'
        data= {data}
        columns={columns}
        getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column) => {


        return {
          onClick: (e) => {


            var a = this.state.selected.indexOf(rowInfo.index);


            if (a == -1) {
              // this.setState({selected: array.concat(this.state.selected, [rowInfo.index])});
              this.setState({selected: [...this.state.selected, rowInfo.index]});
              // Pass props to the React component

            }

            var array = this.state.selected;

            if(a != -1){
              array.splice(a, 1);
              this.setState({selected: array});


            }
          },
          // #393740 - Lighter, selected row
          // #302f36 - Darker, not selected row
          style: {background: this.state.selected.indexOf(rowInfo.index) != -1 ? '#393740': '#302f36'},


        }


        }}
        noDataText = "No available threats"
        />

    )
}
}


  export default ThreatReportTable;
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer you selected is correct, however if you are using a sorting table it will crash since rowInfo will became undefined as you search, would recommend using this function instead

```
                getTrGroupProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
                    if (rowInfo !== undefined) {
                        return {
                            onClick: (e, handleOriginal) => {
                              console.log('It was in this row:', rowInfo)
                              this.setState({
                                  firstNameState: rowInfo.row.firstName,
                                  lastNameState: rowInfo.row.lastName,
                                  selectedIndex: rowInfo.original.id
                              })
                            },
                            style: {
                                cursor: 'pointer',
                                background: rowInfo.original.id === this.state.selectedIndex ? '#00afec' : 'white',
                                color: rowInfo.original.id === this.state.selectedIndex ? 'white' : 'black'
                            }
                        }
                    }}
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the latest version (7.7 at the time) it is possible to select rows using `toggleRoWSelected()` see full example;

```
<tr
  {...row.getRowProps()}
  className="odd:bg-white even:bg-gray-100"
  onClick={() => row.toggleRowSelected()}
>
  {row.cells.map((cell) => {
    return (
      <td {...cell.getCellProps()} className="p-2">
        {cell.render("Cell")}
      </td>
    );
  })}
</tr>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another mechanism for dynamic styling is to define it in the JSX for your component. For example, the following could be used to selectively style the current step in the React tic-tac-toe tutorial (one of the suggested extra credit enhancements:

```
  return (
    <li key={move}>
      <button style={{fontWeight:(move === this.state.stepNumber ? 'bold' : '')}} onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</button>
    </li>
  );
```

Granted, a cleaner approach would be to add/remove a 'selected' CSS class but this direct approach might be helpful in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple rows with checkboxes and select all using `useState()` hooks. Requires minor implementation to adjust to own project.

```
    const data;
    const [ allToggled, setAllToggled ] = useState(false);
    const [ toggled, setToggled ] = useState(Array.from(new Array(data.length), () => false));
    const [ selected, setSelected ] = useState([]);

    const handleToggleAll = allToggled => {
        let selectAll = !allToggled;
        setAllToggled(selectAll);
        let toggledCopy = [];
        let selectedCopy = [];
        data.forEach(function (e, index) {
            toggledCopy.push(selectAll);
            if(selectAll) {
                selectedCopy.push(index);
            }
        });
        setToggled(toggledCopy);
        setSelected(selectedCopy);
    };

    const handleToggle = index => {
        let toggledCopy = [...toggled];
        toggledCopy[index] = !toggledCopy[index];
        setToggled(toggledCopy);
        if( toggledCopy[index] === false ){
            setAllToggled(false);
        }
        else if (allToggled) {
            setAllToggled(false);
        }
    };

....


                Header: state => (
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={allToggled}
                        onChange={() => handleToggleAll(allToggled)}
                    />
                ),
                Cell: row => (
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={toggled[row.index]}
                        onChange={() => handleToggle(row.index)}
                    />
                ),

....

<ReactTable

...
                    getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
                        if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
                            return {
                                onClick: (e, handleOriginal) => {
                                    let present = selected.indexOf(rowInfo.index);
                                    let selectedCopy = selected;

                                    if (present === -1){
                                        selected.push(rowInfo.index);
                                        setSelected(selected);
                                    }

                                    if (present > -1){
                                        selectedCopy.splice(present, 1);
                                        setSelected(selectedCopy);
                                    }

                                    handleToggle(rowInfo.index);
                                },
                                style: {
                                    background: selected.indexOf(rowInfo.index)  > -1 ? '#00afec' : 'white',
                                    color: selected.indexOf(rowInfo.index) > -1 ? 'white' : 'black'
                                },
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            return {}
                        }
                    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# react-table with edit button #
const [rowIndexState, setRowIndexState] = useState(null);
const [rowBackGroundColor, setRowBackGroundColor] = useState('')
{...row.getRowProps({
  onClick: (e) => {
    if (!e.target.cellIndex) {
       setRowIndexState(row.index);
       setRowBackGroundColor('#f4f4f4')
    }
  },
  style: {
   background: row.index === rowIndexState ? rowBackGroundColor : '',
  },              
})}
```

Comment: could you explain the logic behind `!e.target.cellIndex` ?

Answer (score 0):

for version ~8

```js
<tr
  {...row.getRowProps()}
  className="odd:bg-white even:bg-gray-100"
  onClick={() => row.toggleSelected()} <------ (from nick answer the method name is different)
>
  {row.cells.map((cell) => {
    return (
      <td {...cell.getCellProps()} className="p-2">
        {cell.render("Cell")}
      </td>
    );
  })}
</tr>;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).