# react-table: change background color of rows depending upon row props value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v6

I have a situation where I have to change background color of rows depending upon row props. I am currently doing this:

```
const getTrProps = (state, rowInfo, instance) => {
        if (rowInfo) {
            return {
                style: {
                    'background-color': rowInfo.original.customercomplaints.order_ref === currentOrderId ? '' : 'yellow',
                }
            }
        }
        return {};
    }
```

In `react-table`, it is like this:

```
<ReactTableFixedColumns className="-striped"
      columns={customerComplaintsColumns}
      data={customerComplaintsData}
      daultPageSize={10}
      defaultFilterMethod={filterCaseInsensitive}
      getTrProps={getTrProps}
      />
```

If I inspect the element, I do get this:

```
<div class="rt-tr -even" role="row" style="background-color: yellow;">
```

but it doesn't apply on the row. How can I resolve this?

My `react` version is `^16.13.1` and `react-table` version is `6.8.6`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are wrong with assigning style. you might want to pass background-color as object style.

e.g.

```
        return {
            style: {
                'background': rowInfo.original.customercomplaints.order_ref === currentOrderId ? '' : 'yellow',
            }
        }
```

Also instead of passing empty string as default, you might want to pass 'white' or color you want as default.

I think that is the most reason, please let me know if it doesn't work.

Example link which is written by react-table maintainer
https://codesandbox.io/s/k3q43jpl47

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631293/react-table-how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-row-if-it-is-clicked-selec Prob, you might want to check this answer, mostly same question, I guess