# How to get the row index of a clicked cell in react-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

Hello I am working with React Table. Here is my Demo Sandbox - 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vq60okkz20?codemirror=1

I want to get the row index of the clicked cells div. I have two columns where the cells have a clickable div. I want to get the row index for these cells

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select row on click react-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845372/select-row-on-click-react-table)

Answer (score 5):

Straight from the React-table docs:

```
// When any Td element is clicked, we'll log out some information
<ReactTable
  getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
    return {
      onClick: (e, handleOriginal) => {
        console.log("A Td Element was clicked!");
        console.log("It was in this row:", rowInfo);

        // IMPORTANT! React-Table uses onClick internally to trigger
        // events like expanding SubComponents and pivots.
        // By default a custom 'onClick' handler will override this functionality.
        // If you want to fire the original onClick handler, call the
        // 'handleOriginal' function.
        if (handleOriginal) {
          handleOriginal();
        }
      }
    };
  }}
/>
```

The `rowInfo` object will be of this shape:

```
  row: Object, // the materialized row of data
  original: , // the original row of data
  index: '', // the index of the row in the original array
  viewIndex: '', // the index of the row relative to the current view
  level: '', // the nesting level of this row
  nestingPath: '', // the nesting path of this row
  aggregated: '', // true if this row's values were aggregated
  groupedByPivot: '', // true if this row was produced by a pivot
  subRows: '', // any sub rows defined by the `subRowKey` prop
```

By accessing `rowInfo.index` you will get the row index of the cell.
Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nr8w9q6z2m

Comment: probaly `getTrProps` is more suitable

Comment: @tommy123 updated the answer with the working example.

Answer (score 1):

Would i Would suggest is using a onClick handler to get The value out. You Can ad a unique id to get The exact element out.

Here is a Very simple sample

```
<div onClick={this.onClickHandler}></div>


 onClickHandler = (event) =>{
 Let id =event.target.id
... 
//perform operations
 }
```

The id Can be random generated

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a functional rendering this can be help

```
<tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
    rows.slice(0, 10).map((row, i) => {
      prepareRow(row);
      return (
        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
          {row.cells.map((cell, i) => {
            return (
              <td {...row.getRowProps({onClick: (e)=>handleTableCellClick(e,row)})}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
            );
          })}
        </tr>
      );
    })
</tbody>
```