# In react table Select row data and pass the data to different page

Tags: reactjs, react-table

This is my code I have react table with mock data now What I want now is to select the row data which I have mock columns data that means when I click on any table data it should go to another page and display the data on a page how can I do that I am not getting any clue can anyone help in this

```
 function ViewAudits(){
      const data = [{  
        audit_name: 'Sha',  
        address: 'road',
        assignee: 'rav',
        start_date: '11/06/2021',
        created_date: "11/06/2021",
        created_by: "sjr",
        contact_person: "ytr",
        phone: "9875636578"

  
     },
    
    ]  
   const columns = [{   
    Header: 'Audit Name',
    accessor: 'audit_name' 
   },{  
    Header: 'Address',
    accessor: 'address'
  },{  
    Header: 'Assignee',
    accessor: 'assignee'
  },{  
    Header: 'Start Date',
    accessor: 'start_date'
  },{  
    Header: 'Created Date',
    accessor: 'created_date'
  },{  
    Header: 'Created By',
    accessor: 'created_by'
  },{  
    Header: 'Contact Person',
    accessor: 'contact_person'
  },{  
    Header: 'Phone',
    accessor: 'phone'

   }]  

  // const getTrprops = (row) => {console.log("log ",row)}
  return (
     <>
    <Navbar/>
     <div className="container md-5 mt-3">
     <ReactTable  
                  data={data}  
          
                  columns={columns}  
                  defaultPageSize = {2}  
            //       getTrProps={(data, column) => {
            //     return {
            //         onClick: (e, t) => { console.log("clickd",e,t) },
                    
            //     }
            // }}

             
  
                  defaultSorted={[
                           {
                      id: "audit_name",
                      desc: true
                              }
                        ]}
                  pageSizeOptions = {[2,4,6]}  
                  
              />   
        </div>
```

I saw few solutions on this didn't work

Comment: I hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845372/select-row-on-click-react-table

Comment: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/2010

Comment: I have checked this but not working can u modify my code show it once then it would be very helpful mate